# Symfony Make:Migration : The metadata storage is not up to date, please run the sync-metadata-storage command to fix this issue

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, metadata

I keep getting this problem everytime i try to migrate using the commandline: `php bin/console make:migration`
or even `doctrine:migration status`
when i try the `doctrine:migration:sync-metadata-storage` as they tell me I still get the same error message.

I'm currently learning symfony and have been following a guide but I get this problem somehow
Symfony 4.4
php 7.2

Answer (score 183):

Try changing the DATABASE_URL in .env from

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/testtest?serverVersion=10.4.11
```

to

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/testtest?serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.11
```

Symfony documentation suggest specifying the version number but not the database type

"There are more options in config/packages/doctrine.yaml that you can configure, including your server_version (e.g. 5.7 if you're using MySQL 5.7), which may affect how Doctrine functions."
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Original Answer: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/337#issuecomment-645390496

For MariaDB you will need the full semver compat version: Major.Minor.Patch. By executing `mysql --version`, you will get the correct version you are currently running.

Comment: What servertype are you using then?

Comment: Well i use mysql

Comment: If you use XAMPP you can go to: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php to check your server version and type.

Comment: in my case I was using docker so I had to do the same under `environment` in `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: I'm using mariadb 10.5.5 and this fixed the error for me.

Comment: Work for me. I use in my localhost Xampp with mariadb.

Comment: Simply execute "SELECT VERSION()" on your mariaDB server and use this string as version in your config. In my case ?serverVersion=10.3.25-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 and it works.

Comment: prefixing the server version as 'mariadb-10.5.11' or with SELECT VERSION() result '10.5.11-MariaDB-1:10.5.11+maria~focal' doesn't work for me, as a matter of fact any of the proposed solutions work for me except the one proposed by @hashtag-assist. Commenting file vendor lines avoid the error, but editing a vendor file doesn't seem a good solution to me. Are there any other working solution today?

Answer (score 36):

For me was enough prefixing the server version with mariadb-x.x.x. It fixed the issue.

"If you are running a MariaDB database, you should prefix the serverVersion with mariadb- (ex: mariadb-10.2.12)."

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url

Comment: This fixed the issue instantly without having to rewrite config.

Comment: For more details: see https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/337#issuecomment-645390496

And https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/pull/398 to add a documentation to the bundle itself

Comment: Thanks, you solved a long-running issue we had after upgrading to PHP 8.1!

Answer (score 20):

It works if I change the `DATABASE_URL` in `.env`

From:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/testtest?serverVersion=10.4.11
```

To:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/testtest?serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.11
```

Answer (score 17):

In my case, it works when I remove : ?serverVersion=5.2  , from the url.

Comment: Working as charm!

Answer (score 10):

you have to change the `serverVersion=5.7` in *.env* to `serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.8`

Answer (score 10):

Symfony 5.1

if you got:

*Invalid platform version "maridb-10.4.13" specified. The platform version has to be specified in the format: "<major_version>.<minor_version>.<patch_version>".*

just do one of

config/doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    server_version: 'mariadb-10.4.13'
```

or in configuration file
.env

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://databaseUsername:UserPassword@localhost:3306/databaseName?serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.13
```

Comment: I cannot upvote this answer enough. Really wasn't aware that you must specify server_version: 'mariadb-...'.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue after upgrading to Doctrine migrations 3

Seems that a lot of stuff has changed including the table name where migration versions are stored :(

So I updated `config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yaml`, created a new (blank) migration, cleared the cache (just in case) and everything went just fine :)

```
doctrine_migrations:
migrations_paths:
    # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
    # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
    'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations'
storage:
    # Default (SQL table) metadata storage configuration
    table_storage:
        table_name: 'migration_versions'
        version_column_name: 'version'
        version_column_length: 1024
        executed_at_column_name: 'executed_at'
        execution_time_column_name: 'execution_time'
```

BTW. Docs are up to date ;) https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html

Comment: This works for me! Thanks. The "funny" part: I actually had a new project from scratch and got this error, so there was no update. I use Symfony & Doctrine from the beginning. 

Comment: Hang on! I take everything back ... :( The command `make:migration` worked again after I added the storage config to the doctrine_migrations.yaml but `doctrine:migrations:migrate` brought me back to the error: "The metadata storage is not up to date, please run the sync-metadata-storage command to fix this issue.". The same error I get if I run the `doctrine:migrations:sync-metadata-storage` ...

Comment: If use MySQL you need set version_column_length: 255

Comment: What should we put instead of 'migration_versions', 'version', 1024...

@Bukashk0zzz says that you have to use version_column_length: 255 if using mysql, but where did you see that ?

Comment: Because it tries to create an index. And the full search index length in Mysql can only be 255

Answer (score 6):

change

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/testtest?serverVersion=10.4.11
```

To

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/testtest?serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.11
```

Answer (score 5):

I've added `serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.11` in the database URL string, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

for me it worked with me when i removed "?serverVersion=5.7" in .env file

from:   DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/centre?serverVersion=5.7"

to   DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/centre"

Comment: It's seems to be a duplicate of jally-ph's answer

Answer (score 1):

Remove the server version in .env file
`DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/DB_Name`

Comment: doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem it is because of the new version of doctrine migration 3.0

```
php bin/console  debug:config DoctrineMigrationsBundle
```

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here..
I "sloved" it but dont try this at home!

I removed these lines in
`vendor\doctrine\migrations\lib\Doctrine\Migrations\Metadata\Storage\TableMetadataStorage.php`
start on line 191

```
$expectedTable = $this->getExpectedTable();

if ($this->needsUpdate($expectedTable) !== null) {
    throw MetadataStorageError::notUpToDate();
}
```

Then run `make:migration` and `migrations:migrate`.
After success migration paste the function back.

Comment: prefixing the server version as 'mariadb-10.5.11' doesn't work for me, as a matter of fact any of the proposed solutions work for me except this one. Commenting this lines avoid the error, but editing a vendor file doesn't seem a good solution to me. Are there any other working solution today?

Comment: Not sure what I should look for on GitHub. So I came to StackOverflow directly to ask.

Comment: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/337

Answer (score 0):

I temporary resolved this problem by modifying the file: /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/Comparator.php

changed method diffColumn:

```
    // This is a very nasty hack to make comparator work with the legacy json_array type, which should be killed in v3
    if ($this->isALegacyJsonComparison($properties1['type'], $properties2['type'])) {
        array_shift($changedProperties);

        $changedProperties[] = 'comment';
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // This is my change for fix problem//////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if ($properties1['default'] === 'NULL') {
        $properties1['default'] = null;
    }
    if ($properties2['default'] === 'NULL') {
        $properties2['default'] = null;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    // Null values need to be checked additionally as they tell whether to create or drop a default value.
    // null != 0, null != false, null != '' etc. This affects platform's table alteration SQL generation.
    if (($properties1['default'] === null) !== ($properties2['default'] === null)
        || $properties1['default'] != $properties2['default']) {
        $changedProperties[] = 'default';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html

follow the instructions to the letter

> composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle

> php bin/console doctrine:migrations:generate

> php bin/console doctrine:migrations:status --show-versions

> php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate

everything worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle to version 3, this solution worked for me:

Just run: **php bin/console doctrine:migrations:sync-metadata-storage**

Answer (score 0):

In your .env file you can use a default settings pattern:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://db-username:db-password@127.0.0.1/db-name
```

But you need to configure **server_version** in doctrine.yaml

An example configuration can look like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: 'mariadb-10.5.8-focal'
        charset: UTF8
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

In my case, it's **mariadb-10.5.8-focal**.

Answer (score 0):

in your .env file at the database line remove everything after the database name. This should fix the problem!

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of these solutions. In Symfony 6.x version all of these solutions aren't working. But I removed `symfony/web-profiler-bundle` package and everything is fine now. Actually I don't need any profiler. Thanks symfony. I hope you spend my another days in the future.

I will escape from PHP because of symfony framework in near future.

Answer (score -1):

just execute this command

> > symfony console cache:clear

it solve the problem for me a

Answer (score -1):

In my case (MariaDB 10.7.3) setting `?serverVersion=mariadb-10.7.3` didn't help.

I had to uninstall MariaDB 10.7.3 and install [MySQL Community](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) 8.0.28 instead, and then changed DATABASE_URL  to `?serverVersion=8.0.28`

Only switching from MariaDB to MySQL Community fixed this problem for me.